# How do I clone a vector with fixed capacity in Rust?

Tags: rust

By default, when a Vec is cloned, only the minimum capacity needed is allocated for the new Vec:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = Vec::with_capacity(10);
    x.push(1);
    x.push(2);
    x.push(3);
    println!("x capacity: {}", x.capacity()); // 10
    let y = x.clone();
    println!("y capacity: {}", y.capacity()); // 3
}
```

What's the most efficient way to clone the Vec if I want to keep the original capacity? Is there a way to allocate a new vector with a capacity of `x.capacity()` and just memcopy the values from my first vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rust
let mut original_vec: Vec<usize> = Vec::with_capacity(10);
original_vec.push(1);
original_vec.push(2);
original_vec.push(3);

let mut target_vec = Vec::with_capacity(original_vec.capacity());
target_vec.extend(&original_vec);
```

Comment: This will *consume* the `original_vec` making it worse off than a simple move. You'll want to extend with `original_vec.iter().cloned()` to keep both available.

Comment: You can simply pass the `original_vec` as a reference. `target_vec.extend(&original_vec);` I've edited the answer to include the borrow.

Comment: That works too. Today I learned [there's an implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#impl-Extend%3C%26%27a%20T%3E-for-Vec%3CT%2C%20A%3E) for `Vec<T>` to extend from iterator of `&T` if `T: Copy`.